# Java Bound Mismatch in recursive generics/inheritance

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, abstraction

I have the following structure:

`public abstract class A <E extends El, U extends A<E,U> > { ... }`

`public class B<E extends El> extends A<E, B<E> > { ... }`

`public abstract class C <E extends El, T extends A<E, T>> { ... }`

My question is, why can I do this:

`public class R extends C<El, B<El>> { ... }`

but not

`public class R <T extends B<El>> extends C<El, T> { ... }`

Why is `T` (which extends `B<El>`) not a good substitute for `B<El>`?

The exception which I get is 
`Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends A<El,T>> of the type C<E,T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `A` and `C` as follows

```
public abstract class A <E extends El, U extends A<E, ? super U>> {}
public abstract class C <E extends El, T extends A<E, ? super T>> {}
```

Comment: This does make sense, but do you 'see' any solution in avoiding or working around this?

Comment: @Alexandr, seems that my explanation was incorrect. I removed explanation and replaced it with possible solution. If it works for you, fine then. If not, I will delete the answer.

Comment: thank you again! but unfortunately, that does not work. For the methods in C now the following error appears: ```The method x(T, int) in the type C<E,T> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#3-of ?, int)``` where ```public T x(T n, int key){ ... some recursion on x(n,key); ... } ```

Comment: @Alexandr, I have another idea (see the edit). If it does not work, could you add to the question some method signatures which use generic parameters in your `A` and `C` classes? Probably there's something wrong with them (e.g. `? extends` or `? super` should be added).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why can I do this:
>
> `public class R extends C<El, B<El>> { ... }`

Because `El extends El`, and `B<El> extends A<El, B<El>>`

> but not
>
> `public class R<T extends B<El>> extends C<El, T> { ... }`

Because `T` does not extend `A<El, T>`. We know that `T extends B<El>`, and that `B<El> extends A<El, B<El>>`, and not `A<El, T>`. This declaration is in general unsafe.

It's impossible to give any suggestions without knowing what you do with these types inside the classes, and why you think the declaration is safe. For example, if it is known that `A` only serves as a "consumer" of `U`, then you can use a `super` bound and it will work:

```
public abstract class A<E extends El, U extends A<E, ? super U>> { ... }
public abstract class C<E extends El, T extends A<E, ? super T>> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A <E extends El, U extends A<E, U> > {
}

class B<E extends El> extends A<E, B<E> > {
}

abstract class C <E extends El, T extends A<E, ? super T>> {
    public void X(T t, El a) {

    }
}


class R <T extends B<El>> extends C<El, T> {
}
```

Comment: This tends to work and compile, yes, however, consider this: if in ```A```, I have a field of type U and a getter for it, I cannot write ```x(T n, El a) { x(n.getField(), a) }``` without having to specifically cast ```(T)n.getField()```

Comment: It looks like the `B` is only a implementation of the abstract class `A`. If you don't use any specific methods of `B` inside `R` you can remove it and decalre it as:
`class R <T extends A<El, T>> extends C<El, T> { }`.
This way you can go back to previous version of 'C':
`public abstract class C <E extends El, T extends A<E, T>> { ... }`